# React-Native Debug menu on an Android app which is not using any ReactActivity

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

MyReact-Native app uses Native Modules but there is no UI component of react in my app. Now when I try to debug remote JS, I am not able to access js debug menu by shaking my device. However If I add a dummy activity and extend it with ReactActivity it shows me the react debug menu. But in that case it terminates the already running react module I started by implementing ReactApplication interface in my android application class.

Any solution that can allow me to show react debug menu when I shake device, withourt using any ReactActivity in my application?